# this в jquery в коде

Tags: jquery

Есть код(на картинке) Вопрос такой, почему в 4 строчке используется $(this),почему,например,нельзя использовать .bookmark вместо него,это разве не одно и тоже? В данном контексте this-элемент по которому кликнули, но событие задействуется при клике на .bookmark же,или нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Минус за картинку вместо кода

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, по сути. `$(this)` - указывает на конкретный элемент по которому кликнули, в то время как `.bookmark` указывает на все элементы с указанным классом и в итоге `$(this).toggleClass...` будет переключать класс у конкретного элемента по которому кликнули, в то время как `$(.bookmark).toggleClass...` - переключит класс у всех элементов с этим селектором

---

Замечу, что `$(.bookmark).click` - под капотом делает **цикл по всем элементам** с указанным селектором и вешает клик **на все элементы** с селектором, а не вешает событие на один конкретный элемент

Comment: $(this).toggleClass... будет срабатывать на все элементы(которые кликнули) с классом .bookmark?

Comment: @Архангел ну нет же. на один конкретный. на который кликнули

Comment: не так сформулировал,спасибо,я вас понял

Comment: @Архангел ну да, в общем `$(.bookmark).click` делает цикл под капотом по всем элементам. А потом при клике на какой-то элемент с классом `bookmark` будет изменён класс только непосредственно у этого самого кликнутого (при `$(this)`)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ в таком простом коде

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    console.log("$(this)");
    $(this).each(function(idx, el) {
      console.log(el.innerText);
    });
    
    console.log(".btn");
    $(".btn").each(function(idx, el) {
      console.log(el.innerText);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
```